# Regex to match audio files

Tags: javascript, regex, audio

I have multiple files coming from the database to the front-end. To style them properly I would like to extract `videos` and `audio` files into a separate group.

If anyone know how to determine which file is audio and video just by the name of the file `myFile.mp3` or `myFile.wav` that would be nice.

Looks like we have to post the list of all existing audio files
And then create a regex for them.

In any case lets start just with these two `*.wav` and `*.mp3`

Comment: I have a feeling he can make the regex and just needs a list.  If that is true, Google is your friend, because it wasn't hard to get a list of file extensions.  Now all he has to do is pick out the relevant types of audio/video file:  http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/fileextensionsfull.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
/\.(?:wav|mp3)$/i
```

And add all the file extensions you want to filter on.

Answer (score 4):

This should work: `^.*\.(?!wav$|mp3$)[^.]+$`

Comment: This doesn't work as [expected](http://regex101.com/r/oP0rF7). I think you maybe [meant](http://regex101.com/r/zJ4aH9) `^.*(?=\.wav$|\.mp3$)` ?